# How to hyperlink to an item in a QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractitemview

Qt versions used:  4.7.1 and 4.8

I store hierarchical data as nodes in a model that is derived from QAbstractItemModel.  I have a `QTreeView` in my application GUI to display the hierarchical data.  (The data being hierarchical may not be essential for this question;  the general problem I have applies to any kind of data in any model and view.)

I have a textbox (a `QPlainTextEdit` widget, but that is not essential) in my application GUI that displays a hyperlink.  When the user clicks on the hyperlink, I can intercept that and obtain the URL of the hyperlink.  So far, so good.

When I intercept that hyperlink, I am going to make the `QTreeView` navigate to a particular node, expanding its parents as needed so that the user can see it.

The URL of the hyperlink will be in format that lets me know a node is being asked for, and will contain identifying information about that particular node.  For example:

```
<a href="node://something">Click me to see node A</a>
```

So, the question is:  What is the something that can identify that particular node, and that can be encoded as a text string?

I have been reading about `QPersistentModelIndex`.  It sounds like a reasonable thing to start with.  At the time I format the hyperlink, I would definitely know the `QModelIndex` of the particular node, and can construct a `QPersistentModelIndex` from it.  But I am getting lost on how to convert that to a string, and then later convert the string back to a `QModelIndex` from which I can deduce the particular node.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a custom [data role](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole) in your model, and for each of your items set a unique value for this role.

```
//MyModel.h
class MyModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    enum MyRoles {
         UrlRole = Qt::UserRole
    };
    // (...)
}

//MyModel.cpp
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == UrlRole)
    {
        return "uniqueUrl"; //Up to you to decide what you return here
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Then when performing your search, simply use your model's [match function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) to match your unique string and take the first index from the list.

```
QModelIndex MyDialog::getIndexForUrl(QString myUrl)
{
    QModelIndex index = QModelIndex();
    QModelIndexList resultList = ui->treeView->model()->match(QModelIndex(),
        MyModel::UrlRole, "uniqueUrl", 1, Qt::MatchFixedString | Qt::MatchCaseSensitive);

    if (!resultList.empty())
    {
        index = resultList.first();
    }
    return index;
}
```

You may need to adjust the flags and the start index depending on how you defined your model.

Comment: Thank you, @Cendolt.  That is an excellent idea.  I did not know about the `QAbstractItemModel::match()` method.  Your example will likely work as-is for flat data model.  For a hierarchical tree-like data model, I needed a few tweaks, which I will post in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `QAbstractItemModel::match()` to search for items in the data model via a custom data role, as suggested by @Cendolt, is an excellent idea.  I was able to use that idea without having to override `match()` in my custom data model.

The parameters I provide to `QAbstractItemModel::match()` are a little different, though.  In combination with the rest of @Cendolt's example, the following works for my situation.

```
QAbstractItemModel * pModel = ...;

// Start searching from the root of the tree.
QModelIndex startIndex = pModel->index( 0, 0 );

QModelIndexList results = p->match(
  startIndex,
  MyModel::UrlRole,
  "uniqueUrl",
  1,
  Qt::MatchRecursive );
```

### Valid start index

Specifying a starting `QModelIndex` with zeros for the row and column is essential to make the search proceed at all.  When I used a default constructed `QModelIndex`, the search never called my model's `data()` method.  I believe that is because the default constructed `QModelIndex` has -1 for the row and column, which makes it an invalid index.  In the code for `QAbstractItemModel::match()` ({Qt dir}\src\corelib\kernel\qabstractitemmodel.cpp), notice that it skips calling `data()` if the index is invalid.

### Match flags

Specifically for hierarchical data, using the `Qt::MatchRecursive` flag is essential.  Otherwise, the search does not crawl into child nodes.